# Libraries not working despite being installed

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, visual-studio-code, tkinter

I'm what you would call a chatGPT coder. I've taken some coding courses but nothing too intense. I have multiple programs I've created using chatGPT for my business that were running perfectly. All of the sudden my libraries stopped working completly without me changing any code.

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
```

cv2 and numpy are both underlined and not colored in. They also have problems within the script.

CV2 Error

```json
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/samda/Desktop/AutoCrop/AutoCrop.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingImports",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "reportMissingImports"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Import \"cv2\" could not be resolved",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 2,
    "startColumn": 8,
    "endLineNumber": 2,
    "endColumn": 11
}]
```

numpy error

```json
[{
    "resource": "/c:/Users/samda/Desktop/AutoCrop/AutoCrop.py",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
    "code": {
        "value": "reportMissingImports",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "path": "/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "github.com",
            "fragment": "reportMissingImports"
        }
    },
    "severity": 4,
    "message": "Import \"numpy\" could not be resolved",
    "source": "Pylance",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 8,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 13
}]
```

The code is for an automatic image cropper used for taking scans and cropping down to the edges of a subject. When I click the button it's supposed to crop it but does nothing and just confirms that it ran through the code.

Comment: are you using a virtual environment? When you say the library is 'installed', where is it installed? It seems like you are on Windows, so do you use Conda or how did you install those libs? opencv tends to have a lot of dependencies that may need top be installed prior. try installing again and check install logs for errors.

Comment: I'm running it through Visual Studio Code. I installed them in the terminal using pip commands and confirmed that they are installed.

Comment: if you use Visual Studio, then you need to make sure you select the right interpreter, and that you install your libs into the environment for that interpreter. (i.e. activate it before you do pip install)

Comment: That fixed my libraries issue but the program is still not functioning. It runs through all the code and only prints out that the button was clicked.

Comment: you haven't really shared the code so it's not clear what is wrong. maybe post a new thread with the new issue

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 0):

Check the lower right corner of the vscode interface, where the python version you are using is displayed.

[image]

You may have those packages installed, but not necessarily in this python environment, so you need to click on it and select the correct interpreter for the current workspace.

[image]

Or use the following command to install the package for the current environment.

```
path/to/python.exe -m pip install package/name
```

Also note that please use the official extension [Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) to execute the script.

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial*

Comment: I'm currently using 3.8.2 64bit, is that an issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter which version of python you use. As long as the python environment you are using has the packages you need installed.

Comment: Hmm that's odd. The code still does not function properly.

Comment: The issue with your current post should have been resolved. If you have a new question, you can edit another question in detail, or add a specific error message to the current question. It is best to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).